# Problema a criar o objeto em phpmailer: $email = new PHPMailer();

Tags: php, phpmailer

> Eu estou a fazer um projeto e estou a tentar usar o phpmailer para mandar um email a partir do localhost.

```
if (isset($_POST['name']) && isset($_POST['email'])) {
        $name = $_POST['name'];
        $email = $_POST['email'];
        $subject = $_POST['subject'];
        $body = $_POST['body'];

        require "PHPMailer/PHPMailer.php";
        require "PHPMailer/SMTP.php";
        require "PHPMailer/Exception.php";

        $email = new PHPMailer();  <-- Aqui
```

Comment: qual versão do phpmailer?

Answer (score 2):

Olá,

Pelo que notei, não está com problema, apenas com dúvida de como fazer!

Olhe os exemplos na documentação: [PHPMailer/examples](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/tree/master/examples)

Exemplo SMTP:

```
<?php
//Passing `true` enables PHPMailer exceptions
$mail = new PHPMailer();
   
$mail->isSMTP();
$mail->Host = 'smtp.example.com';
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;
$mail->Port = 25;
$mail->Username = 'yourname@example.com';
$mail->Password = 'yourpassword';
$mail->setFrom('list@example.com', 'List manager');
$mail->addReplyTo('list@example.com', 'List manager');

$mail->Subject = 'PHPMailer Simple database mailing list test';

$mail->msgHTML($body);
$mail->AltBody = 'To view the message, please use an HTML compatible email viewer!';

$mail->addAddress($email, $name);
$mail->send(); // TRATE AQUI PARA VER SE ENVIOU MESMO
```

Answer (score 0):

Acho que @Duda Gervásio tem razão, mas acho que você deve estar usando versão 6

```
<?php
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;

// Inclui os arquivo localizados na pasta src
require_once 'PHPMailer/Exception.php';
require_once 'PHPMailer/PHPMailer.php';
require_once 'PHPMailer/SMTP.php';

// Inicia a classe PHPMailer
$mail = new PHPMailer(true); 
$mail->setLanguage('br'); 

//Usado para define o remetente mais adiante
$vemail="usuario@dominio.com";
$vnome="Euzinho"; 

try {
    // Configurações do servidor
    $mail->SMTPDebug = 0; 
    $mail->isSMTP();                                      
    $mail->Host = 'mail.dominio.com';                 // Endereço do servidor SMTP
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true;                          // autenticação SMTP
    $mail->Username = 'usuario@dominio.com';        // Usuário do servidor SMTP
    $mail->Password = '*********';                 // Senha da caixa postal utilizada
    $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';                    // Ativar criptografia TLS, `ssl` também é aceita
    $mail->Port = 587;                           // TCP port to connect to

    // Define o remetente   
    $mail->setFrom($vemail, $vnome);           // email e nome do remetente
    
    
    // Define o(s) destinatário(s)
    $mail->addAddress('ciclano@dominio.com', 'Ciclano');
    
    // Destinatários abaixo são opcionais 
    //$mail->addAddress('beltrano@dominio.com');                  // outro destinatario
    $mail->addReplyTo('eu@meudominio.com', 'Eu');                //aqui você coloca o endereço de quem está enviando a mensagem pela sua página
    //$mail->addCC('cc@example.com');                           // Copia
    //$mail->addBCC('bcc@example.com');                        // Copia oculta

    //Anexos
    //$mail->addAttachment('/var/tmp/file.tar.gz');         // Adicionar um anexo
    //$mail->addAttachment('/tmp/image.jpg', 'new.jpg');   // Nome opcional

    //Content
    $mail->isHTML(true);                                 // true define que o e-mail será enviado como HTML, se false, desativa
    $mail->Subject = 'Digite a assunto aqui';           // Assunto da mensagem
    
    //Define o corpo do email
    $mail->Body    = 'Corpo da mensagem <b>em negrito negritito!</b>';

    $mail->send();
    echo 'Message has been sent';
//caso apresente algum erro é apresentado abaixo com essa exceção.
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo 'Mensagem não pode ser enviada.';
    echo 'Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;   //Mensagem de erro do PHPMailer
}
?>
```